# Hot to get a bold odd-numbered list in LaTeX?

Tags: list, latex, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
   \item Numbered 1
   \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
   \item Numbered 3
   \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
   \item Numbered 5
   \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
   \item Numbered 7
   \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
   \item and so on...
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a better way to get enumerate to give you a list of just the odd numbers without having to add an \addtocounter between every item?

Comment: You may want to visit https://tex.stackexchange.com  (the LaTeX stack exchange) - they may have answers there.

Comment: Here you go: [Skipping every even numbered item in the `enumerate` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184198/5764)

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark the answer below as accepted, if it solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reworking [this reference from TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29851/49683) quickly enough, my first suggestion would be the following, using the environment `itemize` instead of `enumerate`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [\textbf{1}] Numbered 1
  \item [\textbf{3}] Numbered 3
  \item [\textbf{5}] Numbered 5
  \item [\textbf{7}] Numbered 7
  \item [\textbf{9}] and so on...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But then the question may become: *is there a better way to get whay I want ... without having to add a* `\textbf` *to the optional argument of every item?* Of course yes and, to keep it easy, again my first thought was to try the environment `description` here. If you compile the code below, you'll see the two ways "only" differ in indentation. Now the indentation of an environment may be set locally or globally or redefined, but definitely out of this scope.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [\textbf{1}] Numbered 1
  \item [\textbf{3}] Numbered 3
  \item [\textbf{5}] Numbered 5
  \item [\textbf{7}] Numbered 7
  \item [\textbf{9}] and so on...
\end{itemize}

Some text.

\begin{description}
    \item [1] Numbered 1
    \item [3] Numbered 3
    \item [5] Numbered 5
    \item [7] Numbered 7
    \item [9] and so on...
\end{description}
\end{document}
```