# Nesting numbered list inside alphabetical list in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
\item These are the animals in the park:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Dog
        \item Cat
        \item Zebra
    \end{enumerate}
\item These are the people in the park:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Jim
        \item Pete
        \item Carol
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

My output is like this:

```
(a) These are the animals in the park
    (a) Dog
    (b) Cat
    (c) Zebra
(b) These are the people in the park:
    (a) Jim
    (b) Pete
    (c) Carol
```

But I want this:

```
(a) These are the animals in the park
    1. Dog
    2. Cat
    3. Zebra
(b) These are the people in the park:
    1. Jim
    2. Pete
    3. Carol
```

How can I do this? I tried doing another enumerate inside the enumerate without the alpha label but it's still giving me alphabetical numbering.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a problem, if you use the package [`enumerate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and the optional arguments `[(a)]` and `[1.]`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item These are the animals in the park:
  \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Dog
    \item Cat
    \item Zebra
  \end{enumerate}
  \item These are the people in the park:
  \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Jim
    \item Pete
    \item Carol
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output: nested lists as requested]

[Other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47738928/3543233) related to customizing `enumerate` environment. Please comment for any feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try package enumerate:

```
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate*}[label={\alph*)}]
        \item bananas
        \item apples
        \item oranges
        \item lemons
    \end{enumerate*}
```

you can also try this with package tasks:

```
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \begin{question} Which one of fruits is in the basket?
        \begin{tasks}(4)
            \task bananas
            \task apples
            \task oranges
            \task lemons
        \end{tasks}
    \end{question}
```